# Use selected features to generate WHERE clause in ArcGIS for Portal

Tags: sql, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal, where-clause, arcgis-custom-widget

I have a web map in [Portal](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/what-is-portal-for-arcgis-.htm) that has a point layer called Work Orders.

I believe it's possible to manually select points in the layer by using the Web AppBuilder [Select Widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-select.htm).

[image]

Using selected points, I would like to generate a WHERE clause by listing the `WONUM` values in an [`IN CONDITION`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm).

Example:

```
wonum in ('WO1754', 'WO1756', 'WO1759', 'WO1766', 'WO1770', 'WO1772', 'WO1775', 'WO1777')
```

From there, I would **copy** the WHERE clause to a separate work order management system and **paste** it into the system's own [filtering tool](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLKT6_7.6.0/com.ibm.mt.doc/gp_ui/c_SQL_search.html).

**How can I generate a WHERE clause from selected features in Portal?**

*(Oracle 12c)*

Answer (score 2):

Your question somewhat vague, so I'm assuming that you're asking how to design a custom GP Tool (GPService) to run off a widget within your portal app so that it generates some WHERE clause to be consumed elsewhere.

I would use a Feature Set to get the user's target input. Calculate the intersection of the points and the parcels layer to get your parcel IDs for the SQL layer- assuming the IDs are also in the parcel layer. If not maybe use a join to get what you need.

From there you could have your GP Tool write the SQL query to a variety of sources - even if it's a text file in local or network folder. So long as your other program knows where to look it should be fine. And you bury it sufficiently in folders or restrict access to it as to keep curious persons from mucking it up.

As for *how* to generate a WHERE clause - it can be tricky to get the syntax just so. Better to play around with it first to get the syntax down right by either using it inside some script or your database. I suppose if it has to work for your other program you should test out there the syntax requirements and how it reads strings and if you have to do something to handle quote marks, etc.

I've used it to feed a Power BI Gantt chart, so I know data of just about any kind can be exported if you wish. It'll require a good bit of python scripting to do it, but nothing too overwhelming.

for the Record Set if using a python toolbox for the GP Service:

```
param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Draw Target",
    name="in_point",
    datatype="GPFeatureRecordSetLayer",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")

param1.value = r'local_or_Network_path_to_Layer_With_your_Choice_Styling.lyr'
```

...
skip for a while until you need to see if the point is in a polygon,
...

```
target_points = parameters[1].value
    
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(target_points, ["SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        shape_info.append(row[0])
            
#intersect the shape information with the pipes of the selected system:
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(parcels,["WONUM","SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[1].overlaps(shape_info)==True or row[1].contains(shape_info)==True or row[1].touches(shape_info): #this is where the intersect is computed
                target = row[0]
```

This isn't a fully fleshed out script, but maybe it's a start.